# A col in a Pandas DF and a list of data with 2 cols and if colA of the 2nd data list matches with the colA of first DF , assign the second colB value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A col in a Pandas DF and a list of data with 2 cols and if colA of the 2nd data list matches with the colA of first DF, assign the second colB value:

DF:

```
columnA
123
456
789
102
103
104
105
```

Lookup file:

```
ColumnA, ColumnB
123, 001
456, 002
789, 003
102, 004
103, 005
104, 006
105, 007
```

If DF columnA finds a key match in the lookup file with columnA then assign the value from columnB. I used nested np.where but it throws a memory error.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to make the lookup file into a Dataframe `df2` as well and then use

```
dfm = df.merge(df2, on='colA', how='left')
```

the resulting Dataframe will contained the assigned value where found under `colB` and `nan` where no correespondig key was found.